# what does "modular" mean?

Tags: terminology, optimization, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I find some similarity of the concept "[modular set functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermodular_function#Supermodular_functions_of_subsets)" to the cardinality function. But I don't see the cardinality function is also called "modular" or something else.

I wonder what "modular" in the name "modular functions" comes from and means? Is it related to other meanings of "modular"in mathematics (e.g. modular arithmetic)?

Thanks.

Comment: I always assumed a connection to modular lattices, but there is no depth in terminology, it's purely conventional.

Comment: Is it possible you might have better luck at the math SE site? This seems to be more properly a question of math, or possibly of math history. Any connection to computer science would seem to be incidental, although I don't know enough to be sure.

Comment: This looks like a question more suitable for Math.SE.  Our policy is that, generally speaking, questions about mathematics [need to explain in the question their relevance to CS](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/704/755) (e.g., to state the connection to computer science, explain how the question is relevant to computer science, and state why the question is more likely to get a good answer from a computer scientist than a mathematician, if those wouldn't be obvious to other computer scientists).